# How to add document.getElementById value inside a Ruby on Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, getelementbyid

A dynamic value (foo_value) is generated inside the script tag after the page is loaded. I would like to have that value display in the form, so when a user fills out the form, everything including the dynamic value will be stored in the model.

foo_value is dynamic and can be changed until the user submits the form.

foo_value is showing up on the browser console when I check `document.getElementById('foo_value').value`. But it doesn't show up in the `text_field`.

```
<%= form_with(model: fooLand) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :foo %>
    <%= form.text_field :foo, value: "", id: :foo_value %>
  </div>
  ...
<% end %>
```

```
<script>
function generateFooValue() {
    ... //code to generate foo_value
    document.getElementById('foo_value').value = foo_value;
}
</script>
```

Other syntax I've tried for `text_field`:

```
<%= form.text_field :foo, value:"", id: :foo_value %>

<%= form.text_field :foo, id: :foo_value %>

<%= form.text_field :foo, id: "foo_value" %>

<%= form.text_field :foo, value: :foo_value %>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Please add more details. You can accomplish that with js but... you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks Razvans. A dynamic value is generated inside the script tag. I would like to have that value display in the form, so when a user fills out the form, everything including the dynamic value will be stored in the model.

Comment: It's also not clear to me what you're doing here. Is the value available before the page is loaded (ie. in the controller)? If so then `<%= form.text_field :foo, value: @foo_value %>` will work. The JS probably isn't working because "foo_value" is not the id for the field. Check your HTML.

Comment: Hi Sam, foo_value is not in the controller, it is generated from the js after the page is loaded. I also suspect it's the field id, I've tried different syntax (listed at the bottom of the question) but the field is still blank.

Comment: If you're in Chrome you can right click on the field and choose **Inspect**. It will show you the HTML generated and you can get the correct id.

Comment: Thanks Sam. The id seems to be correct, but the value isn't showing on the text_field, I suspect is the syntax. I've been trying Honey's answer and no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <body onload="myFunction()">
    <%= form_with url: '/testing', method: :get, local: true do |form| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :foo %>
        <%= form.text_field :foo, value: "", id: :foo_value %>
      </div>
   <% end %>
 </body>


<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("foo_value").value = 'x';
  }
</script>
```

Updated what I have tried in my rails application. It is worked for me perfectly in my browser. When I open the page, 'x' appears in the text field.

Comment: Thanks Honey. `foo_value` is returning on the browser console but still not showing up on the form. Would it be a matter of syntax on the `form.text_field`? I'll update what I've tried on the question.

Comment: Updated. javascript seems to be working, I could see the value in the browser console, just not inside the Rails form. So I suspect it's the rails form syntax...

Comment: You need to call this generateFooValue() function

Comment: Much appreciate it, Honey. Unfortunately still no luck. During debugging, I've tried a static vale without a function inside the `<script>` tag, and call it on the `text_field` via `id:`, and it still not showing in the `text_field`. So I suspect the issue is on this line `<%= form.text_field :foo, value: "", id: :foo_value %>`

Comment: Thanks Honey. I've marked this as the answer.